# How can I make a fixed responsive top navigation?

Tags: html, css, navigation, fixed

I would like to make a top navigation "fixed" bar.
I'm currently experimenting with the code over on [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar).

Unfortunately the navigation bar is not fixed, how can I make it fixed?

NOTE: I have tried `position: fixed;` but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.fixed-navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

If you use a navbar like that you'll generally want to give it a height (eg 50px) and then offset the rest of your content by that much (eg `margin-top: 50px;` on your content container.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy their code exactly on W3Schools and add the following onto the ul:

```
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
```

You'll get a fixed position on the ul, it will be pushed all the way to the left (no spacing), and all the way up the top (no spacing). Width (100%) just stretches the block across the web-browser (in respect to its size).
You could additionally add a class or an id onto the already existing ul (incase you have multiple existent ul elements) by using `div#fixed-navigation` for id or `div.fixed-navigation` for class (in CSS).

So in total you either have: `<ul id="fixed-navigation">` or `<ul class="fixed-navigation">` (if you choose to use an id or class attribute).

I created a working example for you on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/799rm54n/

Comment: Thanks a lot, but their is one problem. The dropdown got bugged, thanks in advance

Comment: A simple fix that can be reset by changing the dropdowns position additionally to fixed. Allowing it to reposition alongside the newly aligned navigation bar. Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/799rm54n/2/ @KCHere